# Find the connected components of subspace of space with the particular point topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subspace of $X$ with the particular point topology.

Find the connected components of $A$.

Comment: You're being downvoted because you didn't tell us what you tried.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I have no idea

Comment: Also what is a particular point topology?

Comment: you should view on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Divide your analysis into cases depending on whether the subspace $A$ contains the *particular point*.  (In each case you should be able to give a simple description of the subspace topology.)

Answer (score 1):

$S$, a subset of $A$, is open in $A$ iff it is empty or contains $x_0$.

$S$, a subset of $A$, is closed in $A$ iff it is $A$ or doesn't contain $x_0$.

So the only closed and open subsets are $\emptyset$ and $A$ because both $S$ and $S^{c}$ cannot contain $x_0$. Thus $A$ is connected.

EDIT : Oh, too fast. After seeing the upper comment, I realize that my answer is only valid if $x_0 \in A$.

RE-EDIT : Actually, the answer depends on how you understand the question :
X has the particular point topology, or is the topology induced by X on A the particular point topology ?

RE-RE-DIT : Ok, there's the continuation of the argument :
If $x_0 \in A$, then the induced topology on $A$ by $X$ is also the particular point topology, and then $A$ is, as I said, connected, so it has only one connected component, itself.
If $x_0 \not \in A$, then you have to show that the induced topology on $A$ by $X$ is the discrete topology, i.e. for every $B \subseteq A$, there is $B' \subseteq X$ such that $B' \cap A = B$. The connected components of a discrete space being the points, the problem is now solved.

Comment: but we need find connected components of $A$

Comment: that is X has the particular point topology